# Define the following distribution in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose $f$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^1$. Show that $\langle F, \phi \rangle=\langle f, \phi_y \rangle$, for $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, where $\phi_y(x)=\phi(x,y)$ (here $y$ is fixed), defines a distribution in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My question lies in showing how the function is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Really appreciate the help! Thank you :)

Comment: I would say $F=1_y \otimes f$ where $1_y$ is the constant 1 function of variable $y$.

Comment: @Icv how would I use this to show that it is continuous so F would be a distribution?

Comment: If you use that result you don't need anything else. The tensor product of distributions is a distribution (on the relative space). But that result is indeed more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

OK I will use the heuristic integral notation for the pairing of a distribution with a test function, i.e., what I said I would avoid in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free

Here $f(x)$ is a generalized function of the single variable $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Now the quantity $\langle F,\phi\rangle$ defined by $\langle f,\phi_y\rangle$ should be
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\phi(x,y)\ dx\ .
$$
This is not a number, but a function of the variable $y$ which has not been "integrated over". This function belongs to $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e., is a smooth compactly supported function of $y$. This is part of the statement of Fubini's Theorem for distributions, in the $\mathscr{D},\mathscr{D}'$ variant (see my answer to the above MO question for the $\mathscr{S},\mathscr{S}'$ variant).

Now what lcv proposes makes perfect sense but is something different: the application of the distribution $f\otimes 1\in\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ on the test function $\phi\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which indeed produces a number. Heuristically this is 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} f(x)\phi(x,y)\ dx dy
$$

where this time $y$ has been integrated over.

Comment: So essentially, if f is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ then F is also continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @Anon: What you said is not clear. By "$f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$"  do you mean: $f$. which is a (linear) function from $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb{R}$, is continuous on $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Since $f$ is a distribution I know that it is continuous. How do you show that the distribution F is also continuous?

Comment: That's a property of the tensor product of two distributions, here $f$ and the distribution corresponding to the constant function equal to $1$. In the particular situation considered here you can take the second integral I wrote and bound its absolute value by $||\phi||$ for a suitable continuous seminorm $||\cdot||$ on $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. For the latter see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234025/why-is-multiplication-on-the-space-of-smooth-functions-with-compact-support-cont/234503#234503